# scheduling python script with crontab (mac) - unable to import required dependencies

Tags: python, numpy, cron, anaconda, conda

I am trying to use crontab to schedule a python script to run every day, but I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/name/Desktop/Scrape/scraper.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.10 from "/usr/local/bin/python3"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.23.1"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

I checked the versions and they are correct. Numpy, pandas and python are also present in my conda list

Here is my crontab command:

```
* * * * * PYTHONPATH=/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/name/Desktop/Scrape/scraper.py
```

(***** as I'm trying to debug)

I have tried: uninstalling and reinstalling pandas & numpy, creating and activating conda environment. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.10 (`usr/local/bin/python3`) cannot use the site packages from Python 3.9.

Instead of side-loading Conda packages into a system-level install via PYTHONPATH, consider creating a dedicated environment for the task that only has the required packages installed. For example,

```bash
## include whatever other packages you need ...
conda create -n scrape python=3.10 numpy pandas
```

Then have cron run

```bash
conda run -n scrape python scraper.py
```

where `scrape` is the (arbitrary) name of the environment.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How can I create a dedicated environment? Do I activate an environment with conda, and just conda install while the environment is active?

Comment: @Okay updated answer